# Why does RStudio cut off the width of HTML Tables? Is there a setting that can control the size of HTML tables?

Tags: r, rstudio

In RStudio, using RMarkdown, it looks like my HTML tables are being cut off at a fixed width! I can't find the setting to control this, and I've searched around, but can't find anything online that can help me.

Do you guys know what is happening here, and how I can control the width of these tables?

Thank you in advance!

In the code I have included here, you can see:

1. I've created a 30x30 data.frame,
2. A tibble gets displayed as typical,
3. A text print out looks typical,
4. A all the HTML tables look cut off? Regardless of which package or function I use. I've tried:

   4.1. `knitr::kable()`

   4.2. `kableExtra::kable_styling()`

   4.3. `formattable::formattable()`
5. This does not effect figures. I've tried `ggplot()`, and it displays fine.
6. It looks like RStudio is rendering the HTML Table as `class="gwt-Frame"`. Which is distinctly different from a `ggplot2` figure, which is rendered as a `class="gwt-Image"`.

Here's the code I have tried:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
# Create a simple 30x30 table
data <- matrix(1:(30*30),ncol=30,byrow=T) %>% data.frame()
```

```
#Tibble's are typical...
data
```

```
# Text output looks typical
data %>% print.data.frame()
```

```
# The kable() (HTML tables) gets cut off at column 27!! It looks like it's a fixed width??
data %>% knitr::kable()
```

```
# Same for kable_styling()!!
data %>% knitr::kable() %>% kableExtra::kable_styling()
```

```
# Same for formattable()!!
data %>% formattable::formattable()
```

```
# The full_width option of kable_styling() doesn't help.
data %>% 
    knitr::kable() %>% 
    kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"),
                  full_width=T,
                  position="left")
```

```
# This issue does not affect figures.
data %>% 
    reshape2::melt() %>% 
    ggplot(aes(variable,value)) +
    geom_point()
```

I've linked to some screen shots for your convenience:

[Start and Tibble](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtsghSaYOXZQnMkSFEj-RGi6qfwUvQ)

[Text Output](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtsghSaYOXZQnMkTnKSvUZZ7-vcYKg)

[kable](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtsghSaYOXZQnMkUvWsx8fWfZgrcsg)

[kable_styling](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtsghSaYOXZQnMkWirtwtSExC-og1Q)

[formattable](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtsghSaYOXZQnMkV9v89X3EH0vZJKg)

[kable_styling(full_width=T)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtsghSaYOXZQnMkV9v89X3EH0vZJKg)

[RStudio Rendering](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtsghSaYOXZQnMkYezJTwyd9YlRuAQ)

Can you please help me understand what is happening, and what I can do to control the width of the HTML Tables in my RStudio RMarkdown files?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I was unable to recreate your issue with the following bare-bones R Markdown code:

````html
---
output: html_document
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

```{r, results = 'asis'}
matrix(1:(30*30), ncol = 30, byrow = T) %>% data.frame() %>% knitr::kable()
```
````

[image]

Are there any other options you've changed using `knitr`? If not, I'd suggest adding the following CSS code to the beginning of your R Markdown document to set the usable width of the HTML page to match the display width:

```
<style type="text/css">
div.main-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
```

Instead of `100%`, you can use definite widths, such as `1080px` or `1440px`, as well.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin. When I knit the document together, it renders the tables differently. All the sizes are different, which is what I would expect for the different packages. However, my issue is not with the knitted document, but the raw `.Rmd` file. When I execute the code chunks within the RMarkdown Source Editor, all the HTML Tables are cut off at the same width. Have you experienced this issue before?

Comment: May I ask why you are concerned about the rendering of the HTML tables inside the R Markdown document? It seems slightly arbitrary to be concerned about an intermediate product. I'd have to imagine that the width is limited to 800 pixels just to avoid the table from extending past the borders of the R Markdown window.